# How to build a custom login page to authenticate a Lightning app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

We've built a hybrid mobile app that uses a webview which loads up a Lightning application.

When the user loads the app for the first time, it redirects to Salesforce standard login page (login.salesforce.com).

We want to create our own totally custom login page, which would allow us to bypass the standard salesforce login, and authenticate the user navigating to the Lightning application

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 2 solutions:

1. [Customize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_custom_login.htm) your login page.
2. Create your own web page and use authentication, this is a bit difficult but possible, try learning how to do that [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm).

Good luck!!!